# bootstrap-select inside bootstrap grid and panel layout becomes too big upon window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying out bootstrap-select instead of the regular bootstrap select ( < select >with form-control class) and it's great until i attempt to resize the page. The selectpicker doesn't fit into my panel anymore if i make the window smaller which is a shame. This is my html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Basic information</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Chain</span>
     <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"> 
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any smart way to make the select align inside the column/panel even though the text in the options of the select are too big(crop it instead) upon resizing the window? It needs to be dynamic so you can resize the screen to whatever size you want without it breaking the panel. Image to showcase the problem:

[image]

**Edit - Bootstrap structure of the page:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading">Panel 1</div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">Normal select (works)</span>
           <select class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">Selectpicker (breaks panel)</span>
          <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"> 
      </select></div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbnxf2zm/

Comment: Did you try the add some css like overflow:hidden?

Comment: @oguzhancerit not quite what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there is too much text in the select box and the browser wants to show it all. If you don't want to show it all you can wrap the `.form-control` in a div with the max width you allow and since the `.form-control` class has `width: 100%` it will only allow it to go that width.

However, I tested your code and it will hide any input that is too long when I tried it. I need more code in order to understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the tip, I will try this approach. The problem occurs with really long text and you resize the page to about half - i edited it in the structure of the page with 1 normal select and a selectpicker.

Comment: For some reason `selectpicker` is causing the overflow issue. Do you need to use it for what you are doing? The code looks the same even without it

Comment: I would like to use it because of the inbuilt search function and extra features (less coding)

Comment: Did you try this somewhere other than jsfiddle? I tried the exact code you posted elsewhere and I had no problem

Comment: Did you include the .css and .js for bootstrap-select? It works fine if none of those are included but then you don't get the additional functionality with search and stuff upon clicking the select

Comment: And yes I tried on my own website and it was same error. For some reason on JSfiddle if i include the .JS before .CSS for bootstrap-select, it doesnt even show the select. Something for sure is bugged.

Comment: After looking it over, between the fact that you have a span before the dropdown and also the fact that JavaScript is rendering the selectpicker, I think your easiest solution is to use JavaScript to set the width every time the user readjusts the width of the screen. If you don't use the selectpicker it also would work, but if you want to use it, that would be my recommendation

Comment: It appears that if you remove input-group, it becomes responsive again but obviously that means i can't have the same label since it's a part of the input-group class. I think adding another label is easier in this case. https://jsfiddle.net/Lfc33gy4/2/ (check second panel)